# jQuery .on("click") - alternative to .live()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-on

In my project I am appending several buttons to a div:

```
$(".tab-content").append("<div class='landing_content'><button class='off-screen-nav-button btn btn-info btn_edit' data-effeckt='effeckt-off-screen-nav-right-overlay'>Edit</button></div>");
```

and then listen for a click with the following code:

```
$(".tab-content").on("click",".btn-edit",function(){
  console.log('edit');
});
```

Why is this not working? I am used to use .live() but it has been deprecated.

Thanks.

Comment: At time you are binding handler, ".tab-content" element has to be in the DOM. And fix your selector or class name

Comment: `btn_edit` and `landing_content` is invalid for class/id names as underscores are not valid/supported (except strangely in some I.E. version)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your markup you have `btn_edit` and in your jQuery you have `btn-edit`.

Change your markup `class` to match the jQuery selector, like this:

```
$(".tab-content").append("<div class='landing_content'><button class='off-screen-nav-button btn btn-info btn-edit' data-effeckt='effeckt-off-screen-nav-right-overlay'>Edit</button></div>");
```

Comment: Hahaha :D Sorry 'bout that. Always nice to get a fresh set of eyes. Sometimes you can get lost in all the code.

Comment: @CasperSlynge - no worries, sometimes the more you stare at your own code the more it looks right and the more frustrating it is to figure out why it is broken. This is what StackOverflow is for. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The reason your method didn't work (aside from what was pointed out about `btn-edit`) could be because you were attempting to bind an event to an element that didn't actually exist in the DOM until after it was appended, there used to be LIVE which has been depreciated but you can do this instead:

```
//bind the event to the document which always exists and specify the selector
//as the second argument 
$(document).on("click",".tab-content .btn-edit",function(){
    console.log('edit');
});
```

Hope this helps see jQueries on documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more help.

Comment: @CasperSlynge what were you sorry about? :S

Comment: It was for the answer above.